Spring boot tests configuration
So I'm trying to configure my integration tests and I'm facing "unable to connect to Redis" every time.
I have the following initializer class:
@Slf4j
public class DatabaseContainersInitializer implements
        ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        GenericContainer<?> redisContainer = new GenericContainer<>("public.ecr.aws/docker/library/redis:alpine3.19")
                .withExposedPorts(6379);
        redisContainer.start();

        TestPropertyValues.of(
                "spring.redis.host=" + redisContainer.getHost(),
                "spring.redis.port=" + redisContainer.getMappedPort(6379)
        ).applyTo(applicationContext);

        log.info("Redis container started: " + redisContainer.getHost() + ":" + redisContainer.getMappedPort(6379));
    }
}

and abstract test class:
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = DatabaseContainersInitializer.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class BaseIT extends GeneralConstants {
...

and I'm getting:
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
So it seems that it uses default port to connect to redis and I don't understand whats wrong with my configuration.
I have also tried:
System.setProperty("spring.redis.host", redisContainer.getHost());
System.setProperty("spring.redis.port", redisContainer.getMappedPort(6379).toString());

and
    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource(
            "testcontainers",
            Map.of("spring.redis.host", redisContainer.getHost(),
                    "spring.redis.port", redisContainer.getMappedPort(6379))
    ));

container for redis is created successfully by the way

2 Things I would check


Check your docker container list to see if the container is failing to create for some reason


If you dont see any failures in the docker container list, then try placing a long sleep in your application after redis is supposed to have started, and check Docker as well as try to connect using redis-cli. I have a feeling your container is either failing to start or is improperly configured.



There is a section of the Spring Boot documentation that is dedicated to setting properties dynamically from a Testcontainers container: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/testing/testcontainers.html#testing.testcontainers.dynamic-properties
